# Android Rotation Vector sensor and Rotation Matrix

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-sensors, rotational-matrices

I'm new in the rotation matrices field and I'm trying to understand the behave of the Rotation Vector Sensor. I can't understand the relation between yaw, pith and roll with the values returned by the Rotation Vector Sensor.

I checked the source code of the **SensorManager.getRotationMatrixFromVector()** [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/hardware/SensorManager.java) and the [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEvent.html). The Rotation vector sensor returns the following values:

```
values[0]: x*sin(θ/2)
values[1]: y*sin(θ/2)
values[2]: z*sin(θ/2)
values[3]: cos(θ/2)
values[4]: estimated heading Accuracy (in radians) (-1 if unavailable)
```

From the documentation: *"the device has rotated through an angle θ around an axis (x, y, z)"*. So my dubt now is, what is θ? And what are x,y and z? 
Following [this](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/assets/faq_quaternions/index.html#Q26) tutorial from the OpenGL documentation, to rotate a vector V I need the pith, roll and yaw values with which I build the rotation matrix. At the end I have to multiply this matrix by V to rotate the vector. If I'm right, this matrix is different from the one related to the *values* vector obtained using **SensorManager.getRotationMatrixFromVector()**. Am I right? So what represents that matrix?

Comment: I'm also still getting my head around how this all hangs together but from what I've seen so far I believe you need to call `SensorManager.getOrientation()` (with result of `SensorManager.getRotationMatrixFromVector()`)